# Hidden value not posted

Tags: php, mysql, post, hidden

I have some Problems with the following code.
The hidden field is not posted to the next page.
I have tried to put it next to the option field, but that creates some different problems like duplicating the dropdownmenue.

can anyone help me please?

```
<?php 
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = '-----';
    $dbpass = '-----';
    $db = '-----';

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
    mysql_select_db($db);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM Eintraege"; $result = mysql_query($query); 
?> 

<form action="deletescript.php" method="post">



<select name="loeschen"> 
<?php 
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
?> 
<option value="<?php echo $line['ID'];?>"><?php echo $line['Titel'];?></option>   
<?php 
    } 
?> 
</select>



<?php 
    while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { 
?> 
    <input type="hidden" name="titel" value="<?php echo $line['Titel'];?>" />
<?php 
    } 
?> 




    Vorname <br /><input type="text" name="name" value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
    Name <br /><input type="text" name="vorname" value="" class="text" /><br /><br />
    Email <br /><input type="text" name="email" value="" class="text" /><br /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Multiple `titel` inputs will overwrite each other in the post so you'll only get the last one.

Comment: And... you would need `mysql_data_seek()` to reset after the first loop, or build an array in the first.  Also, get off `mysql_`.   Try `mysqli_` or PDO.

Comment: @AbraCadaver - Yes, this is the correct answer, imho.

Comment: `reset($line)` could be the solution. Wait for a better one.

Answer (score 0):

You should at least use `mysqli`, making sure you have the connection on a secure page like:

```
// connect.php
<?php
function db(){
  return new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
}
?>
```

You have a couple of other problems too.

1) Since `mysql_fetch_array()` always returns the next row of results, when `mysql_fetch_array()` is called again in your second while loop, `$line` is `falsey`, because there are no more rows to fetch, so the loop does not run. You could `reset($line)` if you're using fetch like that, but I recommend otherwise.

2) You cannot use the same HTML `name` attribute twice, unless you add `[]` to the end of it. Then you can access it as an Array in PHP.

```
// otherpage.php
<?php
include 'connect.php'; $db = db(); $opts = $hdns = '';
if($q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Eintraege')){
  if($q->num_rows > 0){
    while($r = $q->fetch_object()){
      $t = $r->Titel;
      $opts .= "<option value='$t'>$t</option>";
      $hdns .= "<input name='titel[]' type='hidden' value='$t' />";
    }
    // now you can echo $opts and $hdns where you want
  }
  else{
    $errors[] = 'No result rows were found';
  }
  $q->free();
}
else{
  $errors[] = 'database connection failure';
}
$db->close(); if(isset($errors))die(implode(' & ', $errors));
?>
```

To get the `titel` named inputs on the page you are submitting to, it's like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['titel'])){
  // get each one
  foreach($_POST['titel'] as $t){
    // $t is each one
  } 
}
?>
```

Note that getting data to put into hidden inputs then sending it back to the server is generally pointless, since you have access to that information anyways. You'll want to learn AJAX if you want something to go to the database based on Client input.